# How can I repair vinyl siding

Tags: vinyl-siding

The previous owner of my house hung a hose reel with screws through vinyl siding. The reel came down and the holes are so stripped that even a sizeable lag has nothing to grip. I think I have to move a few inches to find a stud. But how can I hide the holes? I'm thinking of filling with paintable putty and touching up with paint mixed to match. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a scrap of the existing siding from somewhere where it won't be noticed by cutting a full length section from it.  (And then buy a new piece to replace it.)

Cut out the damaged section and replace it with the "scrap" from above.

There are step-by-step instructions [here](http://www.thisoldhouse.com/toh/video/0,,1630939,00.html) and a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJU9cR9u0ws) (skip to 0:01:00 to miss the clothing advertisement) showing the relevant skills.

Comment: Thanks.  That's a fine technique that I'll keep in mind.  It's a bit impractical in this case because the old hose hanger had two mounting screws, one above the other and while the siding is that two-clapboards-per-strip kind, they nicely put the screws through the top of the end of one and the bottom of the middle of the next row.  I'm not going to do *that* much patching when I can get a hose hanger with some body to just cover the whole area.